# How to use my own fork of a package in spacemacs

Tags: spacemacs

How would I go about using my own fork of some core packages in spacemacs? So for example I'd like to use my own fork of spaceline, but I would like to keep the modifications that spacemacs does for it.

I tried doing this in `layers/+spacemacs/spacemacs-modeline/packages.el`:

```
(setq spacemacs-modeline-packages
      '(
        anzu
        fancy-battery
        ;; dependency of spaceline-all-the-icons which came from
        ;; the emacs wiki, we fetch it from Emacs Mirror for now.
        ;; TODO eventually remove this if font-lock+ is available
        ;; in an ELPA repository.
        (font-lock+ :step pre
                    :location (recipe :fetcher github
                                      :repo emacsmirror/font-lock-plus))
        neotree
        (spaceline :location local)
        (spaceline-all-the-icons :location local)
        symon
        (vim-powerline :location local)
        ))
```

and symlinked the local copy of my forks to spaceline and spaceline-all-the-icons to the local folder, but it just uninstalled all the packages related to those and gave me errors about undefined functions

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this, but the simplest of all is changing the location parameter of use-package to point directly to your own fork:

```
(spaceline :location (recipe :fetcher github
                             :repo me/spaceline))
```

In case you want to use the `local` location, then you'll have to have a folder called `local` at the same directory level as the `packages.el` file, and the `local` folder will have subfolders with package names. See example from the spacemacs-defaults layer:

```
.
├── local/
│   └── help-fns+/
│       └── help-fns+.el
├── README.org
├── config.el
├── funcs.el
├── keybindings.el
└── packages.el
```

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I did. I need to try it out again. And try the github recipe too.